# Access ContentPage from IMarkupExtension

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my ContentPage, I'm using an IMarkupExtension to localize Strings. How can I access the root ContentPage from the IMarkupExtension ProvideValue() Method?

Within the ProvideValue() method, I see no possibility to access the ContentPage object. But for error handling etc, I need to access some members of the ContentPage object.

ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    [...]
    x:Name="Page1"
    >

    <ToolbarItem [...] Text="{local:Translate MENUE_LOGIN}"  />

    [...]
</ContentPage>
```

IMarkupExtension:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    [...]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
         // How can I access Page1 here???
    }
}
```

As I don't can insert an object reference via constructor, how I can access the ContentPage at all to use its methods?

Comment: What logic for error handling are you trying to accomplish that you need to have a reference to a page in the `IMarkupExtension`?

Comment: Basically, I catch all exceptions that may ever occur in my application and log them. The logging method is a member of the ContentPage which persists the error directly to make a further logfile analysis possible. And yes, its unlikely that an exception is thrown in the ProvideValue() method, but anyway. If it occurs when a client is running my app, I want to have this exception logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't always agree with using this method of notifying other classes and such via this method, this might be the best situation for you. Look into `MessagingCenter`. This allows you to register strings as an event and when you notify the **Exception** event, your page can listen to that event and do the appropriate action(s).

Here is the documentation for [Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

If you aren't displaying the error to the user and just logging it to a file or `AppCenter`, you can register to listen for the particular **MessagingCenter** action via your logger class.

Comment: This fits me need perfectly. Thanks a lot for pointing this out! I was not aware of that Xamarin.Forms already has a built-in Message broker.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update 03/30/20 - Use reflection to access non-public `ParentObjects`

You can use `serviceProvider` to access the service that implements `IProvideParentValues`; which in turn should be able to provide the parent-object(s) for target element.

*Caution: This solution uses reflection, so use this option sparingly - as it might break with later versions of Xamarin.Forms*

Note: Only tested with current version Xamarin.Forms <= 4.5.0

For example:

```
private PropertyInfo cachedPropertyInfo = null;

public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (serviceProvider == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        
    var valueProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<IProvideValueTarget>()    
                            ?? throw new ArgumentException("serviceProvider does not provide an IProvideValueTarget");

    cachedPropertyInfo = cachedPropertyInfo ??
        valueProvider.GetType().GetProperty("Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IProvideParentValues.ParentObjects", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if(cachedPropertyInfo != null)
    {
        var parentObjects = cachedPropertyInfo.GetValue(valueProvider) as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (parentObjects == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to access parent objects");

        foreach (var target in parentObjects)
        {
            if (!(target is Page page))
                continue;

            // ---->>> Access target here for root parent page.
        }
    }

    throw new XamlParseException($"Unable to access parent page");
}
```

This is how `StaticResource` or `Reference` extensions access the parent or root objects.

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticResourceExtension.cs
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/ReferenceExtension.cs

Comment: unfortunately `IProvideParentValues` and `ParentObjects` are internal and therefore cannot be used in my code

Comment: @Sharada Gururaj IProvideParentValues is internal ... Is there another solution for getting ContentPage ?

Comment: @DenisKotov I guess we can use reflection to access ParentObjects property. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SharadaGururaj Thank you for updated answer !! I have asked the similiar question and I have mentioned you in https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/407351#Comment_407351